# Disk volume not extending

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, diskmanagement, diskpart

C: volume on a virtual disk within a Server 2008 R2 virtual machine won't extend correctly.

Under Disk Management, Disk 0 is showing 119.9 GB NTFS for the C: volume, however C: under Windows Explorer only shows it as 100 GB.

I have tried extending the volume under both Disk Management and using DISKPART from the command line. DISKPART shows error "DiskPart has encountered an error: The device does not recognize the command.
See the System Event Log for more information."

[image: Disk Management]

[image: DISKPART]

Comment: `See the System Event Log for more information.` - What's in the event log?

Comment: Have you tried just using `extend` without arguments?

Comment: I cannot see any events being logged in Event Viewer when running 'extend filesystem'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no chance to extend the volume of c using diskpart.
U should use third party software.
https://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express

download it and work with its feature

Comment: I tested EaseUS Partition Master due its support of Windows Server OS's. Unfortunately it reports the same as Disk Management - disk capacity is 119 GB. C:\ under Windows Explorer still reports as being 100 GB.

Comment: send me screenshot with error